# gcc utf-8 string literal compile error

Tags: utf-8, string-literals, gcc4.7

I'm using g++(GCC) 4.7.2 on Ubuntu. 
Just trying to figure out how to get the "u8" string literal prefix to compile.
I thought it was "built in" with this version of gcc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int 
main ()
{
  std::string example1 = u8"Abcd";
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

> > $ g++ -Wall -B/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ helloworld.cpp -o hello helloworld.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: helloworld.cpp:12:26: error:
> >     ‘u8’ was not declared in this scope helloworld.cpp:12:28: error:
> >     expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before string constant helloworld.cpp:12:15:
> >     warning: unused variable ‘example1’ [-Wunused-variable]

I use the "-B" option because that is where my crt1.o and crti.o reside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a c++11 feature, so add `-std=c++0x` to your command line. That works for me with g++ 4.6.3, on 4.7.2 `-std=c++11` might work too